# Powershell 2.0 Get users for a local group

Tags: powershell-2.0

How can I get user list from a local group? I only have PS 2.0 and it does not have Get-ADGroup command.

I can get local groups:

```
$adsi = [ADSI]"WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME"
$groups = $adsi.Children | Where { $_.SchemaClassName -eq 'Group' }
$group | ft Name
```

What I need is to list all the members for each group.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following

```
$obj = [ADSI]"WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME"
$admingroup = $obj.Children | Where { $_.SchemaClassName -eq 'group'} |  where {$_.name -eq 'Administrators'}
$admingroup.Invoke('Members') | % {$_.GetType().InvokeMember('Name', 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)}
$admingroup.Invoke('Members') | % {$_.GetType().InvokeMember('Name', 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)}
```

Here are the common properties

**String** :

```
Description, FullName, HomeDirectory, HomeDirDrive, Profile, LoginScript, ObjectSID
```

**Integer** :

```
UserFlags, PasswordExpired, PrimaryGroupID
```

**Time** :

```
PasswordAge
```

You'll find more in [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$computer = [ADSI]"WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME"

$computer.psbase.children | where { $_.psbase.schemaClassName -eq 'group' } | foreach {
    write-host $_.name
    write-host "------"
    $group =[ADSI]$_.psbase.Path
    $group.psbase.Invoke("Members") | foreach {$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)}
    write-host
}
```

This doesn't give the domain though, hence i had to look for other ways, like:

If you want to see members of a local group quickly:

```
PS C:\> net localgroup USERS
Alias name     USERS
Comment        Users are prevented from making accidental or intentional system-wide changes and can run most applications

Members

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE
The command completed successfully.
```

Now you can manipulate this output a bit to get what you need:

```
$computer = [ADSI]"WinNT://$env:COMPUTERNAME"

$groups = $computer.psbase.children | where { $_.psbase.schemaClassName -eq 'group' } | select -ExpandProperty Name

Foreach($group in $groups)
 {
  write-host $group
  write-host "------"
  net localgroup $group | where {$_ -notmatch "command completed successfully"} | select -skip 6
  Write-host
 }
```

Comment: I tried your codes, the results are very close. All the user names are displayed, but they don't include domain name. For example, user1, instead of domain1\user1.

Comment: Yeah, I struggled to get that too with ADSI provider. I have edited my answer to manipulate output of net localgroup to include Domain names.
You can find the reference [Here](http://powershell.org/wp/2013/04/02/get-local-admin-group-members-in-a-new-old-way-3/)